# How do I repeatedly request to the database in a selected fragment on android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have tried to make repeated requests to the database so that the textview in the fragment gets an update of the value from the database. However, when I move to another fragment, the application becomes force close. Is there a way to make repeated requests but only when the fragment is selected?

```
public class BerandaFragment extends Fragment {
    String user_id, series;
    TextView co, co2, pm25, suhu, kelembaban, tekanan, statusco, statusco2, statuspm25;
    int co_int, co2_int, pm25_int;
    int count = 0;

    public BerandaFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_beranda, container, false);


        //ToolbarName
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Beranda");

        //session user_id
        SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager(getActivity());
        user_id = sessionManager.getUserDetail().get("user_id");

        //session series
        SessionManagerSeries sessionManagerSeries = new SessionManagerSeries(getActivity());
        series = sessionManagerSeries.getPilihSeries().get("series");

        //Bind view layout
        co = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nilaiCO);
        co2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nilaiCO2);
        pm25 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nilaiPM25);
        suhu = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nilaiSuhu);
        kelembaban = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nilaiKelembaban);
        tekanan = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nilaiTekanan);
        statusco = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.statusCO);
        statusco2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.statusCO2);
        statuspm25 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.statusPM25);

        refreshdata();

        return v;
    }

    private void refreshdata() {
        count++;

        Call<DataSensor> dataSensorCall = ApiClient.getInstance().apiInterface().dataSensorResponse(user_id, series);
        dataSensorCall.enqueue(new Callback<DataSensor>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DataSensor> call, Response<DataSensor> response) {

                if (response.body() != null && response.isSuccessful() && response.body().isStatus()){
                    DataSensorData dataSensorData = response.body().getDataSensorData();

                    co_int = Integer.parseInt(dataSensorData.getCo());
                    co2_int = Integer.parseInt(dataSensorData.getCo2());
                    pm25_int = Integer.parseInt(dataSensorData.getPm25());

                    co.setText(dataSensorData.getCo());
                    co2.setText(dataSensorData.getCo2());
                    pm25.setText(dataSensorData.getPm25());
                    suhu.setText(dataSensorData.getSuhu());
                    kelembaban.setText(dataSensorData.getKelembaban());
                    tekanan.setText(dataSensorData.getTekanan());

                    //Status CO
                    if (co_int <= 50){
                        statusco.setText("Baik");
                    } else if (co_int > 50 && co_int <= 100){
                        statusco.setText("Sedang");
                    } else if (co_int > 100 && co_int <= 199){
                        statusco.setText("Tidak sehat");
                    } else if (co_int >= 200 && co_int <= 299){
                        statusco.setText("Sangat tidak sehat");
                    } else {
                        statusco.setText("Berbahaya");
                    }

                    //Status CO2
                    if (co2_int <= 50){
                        statusco2.setText("Baik");
                    } else if (co2_int > 50 && co2_int <= 100){
                        statusco2.setText("Sedang");
                    } else if (co2_int > 100 && co2_int <= 199){
                        statusco2.setText("Tidak sehat");
                    } else if (co2_int >= 200 && co2_int <= 299){
                        statusco2.setText("Sangat tidak sehat");
                    } else {
                        statusco2.setText("Berbahaya");
                    }

                    //Status PM25
                    if (pm25_int <= 50){
                        statuspm25.setText("Baik");
                    } else if (pm25_int > 50 && pm25_int <= 100){
                        statuspm25.setText("Sedang");
                    } else if (pm25_int > 100 && pm25_int <= 199){
                        statuspm25.setText("Tidak sehat");
                    } else if (pm25_int >= 200 && pm25_int <= 299){
                        statuspm25.setText("Sangat tidak sehat");
                    } else {
                        statuspm25.setText("Berbahaya");
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Berhasil memperbarui data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Gagal memperbarui data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DataSensor> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        refresh(3000);
    }

    private void refresh(int miliseconds) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                refreshdata();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, miliseconds);
    }
}
```

And this is the error message:

```
2021-04-17 10:13:49.369 1851-1851/com.example.partyapps E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.partyapps, PID: 1851
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:126)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:289)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:279)
        at com.example.partyapps.Fragment.BerandaFragment$1.onResponse(BerandaFragment.java:138)
        at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1.lambda$onResponse$0$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:89)
        at retrofit2.-$$Lambda$DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$3wC8FyV4pyjrzrYL5U0mlYiviZw.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6698)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:495)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:859)
```

Comment: in which line u r getting this error ??

Comment: on these line

`Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Berhasil memperbarui data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Gagal memperbarui data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Toast.makeText(getContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: did u try to change getContext() to getActivity() ??

Comment: I already changed it all, but still force close. And when the toasts was deleted the app is normal and request to database always running. How to make the request stop when I move to other fragment?

Comment: it wont until you get the all response

Answer (score 0):

i have to one solution, this will definitely work for you.

pass context to the constructor parameter

```
 Context ctx;

public BerandaFragment(Context context) {
        ctx = context;
    }
```

And use it in your toast message or anything that need context

```
Toast.makeText(ctx, "Berhasil memperbarui data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```